# Pandas Return Associated Attributes with .resample()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am resampling 1 min data to monthly using pandas and the .resample('M') method.  I am looking for the way of generating the associated attribute 'symbol' with the returned summary summary.

ex-

```
#1 MO
month_summary = pd.DataFrame()    
month_summary['open'] = df.open.resample('M').first().ffill()    
month_summary.head()
```

returns

```
date        open
2017-06-30  124.989
```

How do I also include asscciated attribute 'symbol' with the corresponding .first() record.

I am looking for something like...

```
#1 MO
month_summary = pd.DataFrame()
month_summary['symbol'] = df.symbol   
month_summary['open'] = df.open.resample('M').first().ffill()
month_summary['closed'] = df.closed.resample('M').last().ffill()    

month_summary.head()
```

to return this.

```
date        symbol    open     close
2017-06-30  EURJPY    124.989  124.282
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you provide sample data

Comment: ffill is the wrong thing to do here. Do you want the first for each symbol?

Comment: @AndyHayden. No just the first open value for the aggregated mo in particular but also return the symbol associated with whichever open value is returned.

Comment: @NoahHuntington but in that case ffill is nonsensical?

Comment: @AndyHayden I wondered this. So if I dropped the ffill() could I return corresponding symbol?

Comment: @NoahHuntington nevertheless added answer.

Comment: @NoahHuntington I think you should just drop the ffill, it doesn't make sense for either the open or the symbol (not sure what it means if the symbol is NaN, but if the open is you _could_ use the ffill from the previous open for that symbol... you could get that with `df.groupby("symbol")["open"].ffill()` or perhaps `df.groupby("symbol")["open"].transform("ffill")` but that's kinda another question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first record for *each* symbol and month:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="M"), "symbol"]).agg({"open": "first", "close": "last"})
```

Note: the ffill *only* makes sense if you are grouping by symbol too, otherwise you might be filling in one symbols open values with the previous (different symbol).

---

Note: You can just get the entire first row using .first on the DataFrame groupby:

```
df.resample('M').first()
```

(without mentioning the column), you can then filter the columns after e.g.

```
df.resample('M').first()[["open", "symbol"]]

df.resample('M').last()[["closed", "symbol"]]
```

Comment: To be clear , I am looking for the first open value regardless of symbol.  Then return whichever symbol is associated with the .first().

Comment: @NoahHuntington that's the part of the answer below the line

Comment: I think I have my answer in that this is nonsensical.  I need to avoid NaN values.  I am also returning 'close' .last() value.  I tried to keep it simple for this post. Its clear to me now that the open value found for the time series does not necessarily share the same symbol as the close value.  I have updated question to reflect this.

Comment: @NoahHuntington the last works the same, just concat them (though not clear to me what symbol to use if they differ).